# gps events and if statements

Tags: python, gps

I am developing a program to produce an event whenever a speed is reached on a gps.  The code I am currently trying to modify is below:

```
from gps import *
import time
import threading
import math

class GpsController(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.gpsd = gps(mode=WATCH_ENABLE) #starting the stream of info
        self.running = False

    def run(self):
        self.running = True
        while self.running:
            # grab EACH set of gpsd info to clear the buffer
            self.gpsd.next()

    def stopController(self):
        self.running = False

    @property
    def fix(self):
        return self.gpsd.fix

    @property
    def utc(self):
        return self.gpsd.utc

    @property
    def satellites(self):
        return self.gpsd.satellites

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create the controller
    gpsc = GpsController() 
    try:
        # start controller
        gpsc.start()
        while True:
            #print "latitude ", gpsc.fix.laif 
            #print "longitude ", gpsc.fix.longitude
            #print "time utc ", gpsc.utc, " + ", gpsc.fix.time
            #print "altitude (m)", gpsc.fix.altitude
            #print "eps ", gpsc.fix.eps
            #print "epx ", gpsc.fix.epx
            #print "epv ", gpsc.fix.epv
            #print "ept ", gpsc.gpsd.fix.ept
            print "speed (m/s) ", gpsc.fix.speed
            #print "climb ", gpsc.fix.climb
            #print "track ", gpsc.fix.track
            #print "mode ", gpsc.fix.mode
            #print "sats ", gpsc.satellites
            time.sleep(1)

#Error
    #except:
     #   print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
      #  raise

    #Ctrl C
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "User cancelled"

    finally:
        print "Stopping gps controller"
        gpsc.stopController()
        #wait for the thread to finish
        gpsc.join()

    print "Done"
```

I am wanting to add an "if" statement to the program to first look at the speed being transmitted and printing or enabling an event whenever the speed reaches a certain number.

I am not sure where and when to add the "if" code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the while loop would make the most sense.  There was no specification as to whether the event should happen once or multiple times when hitting the 'certain amount'.

```
from gps import *
import time
import threading
import math

class GpsController(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.gpsd = gps(mode=WATCH_ENABLE) #starting the stream of info
        self.running = False

    def run(self):
        self.running = True
        while self.running:
            # grab EACH set of gpsd info to clear the buffer
            self.gpsd.next()

    def stopController(self):
        self.running = False

    @property
    def fix(self):
        return self.gpsd.fix

    @property
    def utc(self):
        return self.gpsd.utc

    @property
    def satellites(self):
        return self.gpsd.satellites

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create the controller
    gpsc = GpsController() 
    try:
        # start controller
        gpsc.start()
        while True:
            if gspc.fix.speed > event_trigger_amt:
                print "speed (m/s) ", gpsc.fix.speed
                doEvent()
            time.sleep(1)

    #Ctrl C
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "User cancelled"

    finally:
        print "Stopping gps controller"
        gpsc.stopController()
        #wait for the thread to finish
        gpsc.join()
```

Comment: I did forget to mention that it would be a continuous loop looking at the speed and triggering the event.  I will be testing it by having the event trigger a blinking led in the interim.  Thank you for your help!